# Slow on transaction call from script in ethers.js

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, transactions, ether, ethers.js

I'm using Base chain. however, I see that when i do execute transaction with contract by script (contract.method() -> tx.wait()) it takes too long time. Anyone know why? Because I do send eth by metamask on that chain is not slow like that. ( I use ether.js)